# How can you wait for an end-to-end Step Function test to finish when triggered by EventBridge?

Tags: python, testing, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

We are currently using an event-based approach to process files loaded into S3. When a file is uploaded it triggers an EventBridge S3 event, which kicks off a Step Function. When the data is moved to the target the Step Function finishes.

We are interested in implementing an automated end-to-end test in our Python testing environments (both local and CICD) for this.

How can we properly wait for the Step Function to finish before checking our output location?

There are a few approaches I've considered, each with a drawback:

1. Set a timer, wait n minutes for job to finish - inefficient
2. Add final step to Step Function which writes to SNS, constantly poll SNS for incoming messages - requires new infrastructure just for testing, would be a waste in Production, still inefficient
3. Add tags or parameters to Step Function so we can search for it and find its ARN, then use that to poll for when it finishes - we can't find a way to attach tags when the Step Function is triggered by EventBridge, still somewhat inefficient
4. Constantly check our output location - inefficient
5. Test Step Function using Step Functions Local - still doesn't duplicate the EventBridge trigger, so we're not exactly testing the full end-to-end

Is there a way to find the ARN of the Step Function which has been triggered by an EventBridge event that you intentionally initiated? Is there another effective approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Synchronous Express Workflows for AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-synchronous-express-workflows-for-aws-step-functions/).

This type of Step functions allows you to quickly receive the workflow response (like a synchronous lambda function).

Keep in mind that the max duration for this kind of functions is 5 minutes, it's a good option if your entire process fits in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good option! In our case our tests would probably run in ~6 minutes and some instances could run for much longer so I don't think we can use this.